# Certificados Digitales (FNMT, DNI-E ...) en aplicación asp.net C#

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, certificado-ssl

Necesito que mi aplicación web (escrita en c#) en el proceso de inicio de sesión, obtenga los certificados digitales que el cliente ha instalado en su máquina o el DNI-E si está conectado.

Si le digo dónde está el certificado con una ruta física, lo lee sin problemas, pero no quiero eso, quiero iniciar sesión como en muchas páginas que le das al certificado digital, obtienes la solicitud de certificado y lees el uno que seleccionas.

Dejo una captura, sin datos personales, de lo que estoy buscando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? Es decir, hacer la llamada desde servidor, leer en cliente y recoger el certificado en servidor.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
 public X509Certificate2 ObtenerCertificado()
    {
        X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection col = st.Certificates;
        st.Close();
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(); 
        X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, "Certificados Digitales", "Seleccione su certificado digital", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);


        if (sel.Count > 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2Enumerator en = sel.GetEnumerator();
            en.MoveNext();
            cert = en.Current;
            if (DateTime.Now > cert.NotAfter)
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificado caducado");
            }
            else
            {
                return cert;
            }
        }

        return cert;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más la pregunta? Algunas partes no se entienden, y lo necesitamos para poder ayudarte. Así mismo, compartir el código de como lees los certificados indicando la ruta física.

Comment: Buenas JYass, gracias por la bienvenida.

El proceso es facil, necesito realizar un login en mi aplicación con un certificado digital, que puede ser de los expedidos por la FMNT o el DNI-e.
para ello uso la clase x509Certificate y le indico que lea del almacen de certificados. Si hago la prueba desde Visual Studio el prompt(la ventana) de elegir certificado la veo sin problema, pero cuando lo despliego en IIS no sale. Ahora subo el código.
Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Alberto, no pegues código en los comentarios. Es mejor que pulses en [edit] y añadas ahí toda la información que sea necesaria.Tambien te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, así lo he hecho, he subido el código a la pregunta y miraré lo que me indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes comprobar varias cosas, si en local en modo debug te permite seleccionara un certificado del almacen, revisar la configuración de IIS, [aqui tienes una guía básica](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/02/12/how-to-configure-iis-client-certificate-mapping-authentication-for-iis7/).

Recuerda en el paso 4, activa que se requiera un certificado en cliente desde IIS.

Si quieres mapear individualmente, uno a varios o mediante directorio activo los certificados, dependerá de la versión de IIS:

- [Autenticación de cliente y mapeo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/)

Por otro lado siempre puedes permitir seleccionar cualquier certificado de cliente y comprobar despues que el emisor sea solo uno de los que tu quieras, mostrando el mensaje correspondiente.

- [Referencia Microsoft para ASP.NET Web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315588/how-to-secure-an-asp-net-application-using-client-side-certificates)
- [Ejemplo con MVC](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/25/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-5-working-with-client-certificates-in-a-web-project/)